# using a man page viewer in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, manpage

After having [downloaded](http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/projectPages/libhover/) a Linux Man Page Viewer, I am  not seeing the actual man page when hovering over a function.

Should i enable it somehow? Is where a menu item i should be using?

Please advise

Comment: Check your link, at the moment it leads to unstyled xml document.

Comment: link updated. Thanks for noticing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it requires [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) 5.0.1 and depending on the version of Eclipse you have installed it may not be included.

What Eclipse package do you have installed?

Comment: I run CDT v8.3.0 and Man Page Viewer v1.0.0.201406100404 on Eclipse Kepler and face the same problem.